# Reason for Security Level of AES

Tags: aes

I know that a 128 bit key for AES yields a (around?) 128 bit of security. That means the best attack against the AES scheme is as strong as just brute forcing the key?

What is the intuitively reasoning for this fact?  I think there are mathematical structure in place that should help to find the key easier...

In fact there are symmetric schemes whose security level does not equal the length of the key.

Comment: There is no proof of security in a mathematical sense. It is calculated by the best attacks. There is no attack better than brute-force for a single key search. For multiple targets, you can achieve faster.

Comment: @kelalaka I have to admit that symmetric cryptanalysis is far from my area of expertise, but are you saying the claims in this paper are incorrect (or maybe imprecise)? https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/449

Comment: @Maeher From Wiki: The data complexity of the attack is $2^{88}$. That works out to about 38 trillion terabytes of data, which is more than all the data stored on all the computers on the planet in 2016. Their complexity analyze in section 6.4 is nice. They compare with the actual AES runs. I can say true brute-force comparison. However, the amount of data makes it impractical even you can store it. Assume that you can brute-force 128-bit and store $2^{88}$-bit data you would go with a couple of pairs instead of this attack since the data requirements. Broken, In theory yes, in practice no.

Comment: This is similar to Differential and Linear attacks on DES. Theoretically broken, but the requirements make them impractical. So. you did not see any Differential and Linear attacks implementations on DES. There were only brute force machines that run multiple DES cores in parallel.

Comment: @Maeher The paper may be theoretically interesting, but given a _single_ plaintext/ciphertext pair I can find the key _even faster_ using eight AES circuits in parallel.  It is hard to imagine that the price/performance ratio of this attack, requiring an unimaginable $2^{88}$ oracle queries, is better than a generic attack.  (Much more concerning, of course, is the linear cost reduction of generic multi-target attacks on AES-128, which is why you should use AES-256 instead for a 128-bit security level!)